# Is it possible to generate hash from a human fingerprint?

Tags: image-processing, hash, hashcode, sha256, fingerprint

I want to generate a hash value-from fingerprint. I have seen a paper that used the freeman chain code algorithm to generate the hash value. I have searched so many research papers. But I don't find any proper solution. I want to use the hash value from the fingerprint in my research

Comment: Which kind of the fingerprint do you mean, the fingerprint of humankind as a picture, or some cryptographic tech like fingerprint of user action?

Comment: Fingerprint of humankind